# Does $ p|(2^{2kq}-2^{kq}+1)$ where $p=1+k\cdot q$ ? I'm stuck...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Does $ p|(2^{2kq}-2^{kq}+1)$ ,$p=1+k\cdot q$,where $p,q$ are prime ?

From Fermat's little theorem;
$(2^{2kq}-2^{kq}+1)$ mod $q\equiv (2^{2k}-2^{k}+1)$

This is where I'm stuck, please help.

Thank you...

Comment: I am not sure how you applied little Fermat and got that... given $kq=p-1$, shouldn't $4^{p-1}-2^{p-1}+1$ be congruent to $1-1+1$ mod $p$ as long as $p$ is odd?

Comment: by assuming $(2^k)^q mod q \equiv (2^k)$

Comment: Ah right. But your question is about divisibility by $p$, not $q$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $$2^{p-1}\equiv 1\equiv 2^{kq}\pmod{p}$$

Comment: OK, so $(2^{2kq}-2^{kq}+1)/p =1+c\cdot q$,$\frac{(2^{2kq}-2^{kq})}{kq}=c+k+ckq$; which implies $q|(2^{kq}-1)$.What does this say about $k$?